# Split String into two lines in php

Tags: php

I have a String variable and I need it to be printed in two lines. This is my String.

```
$send = "Thank you for registering. For more details contact us";
```

I need this string to be printed like this

```
Thank you for registering. 
For more details contact us
```

I tried like this

```
 $send = "Thank you for registering.<br/> For more details contact us";
```

But it printed this:

```
 Thank you for registering.<br/> For more details contact us
```

How do I print this as I needed?

Thank you!

Comment: `It printed` where? It depends on whether you are looking at plain text or at html content.

Comment: in a email body. This is a content of a email message I send in my testing application

Comment: If email is a plain text then you should use `\n` (and it should be in a string with double quotes, single quoted string will leave it like this) instead of `<br>`. If email contains an html then something, that 'outputs' your string, converts `<` and `>` into html entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display that String in `HTML`

```
$send = "Thank you for registering.<br/> For more details contact us";
```

And for plain text files

```
$send = "Thank you for registering.\n For more details contact us";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$send = "Thank you for registering.<br/> For more details contact us";
echo $send;
```

This shouldn't be an issue if you're using echo. If this doesn't works, try this:

```
$send = "Thank you for registering.\n For more details contact us";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $send = "Thank you for registering.\n For more details contact us"; ?>
```

If you want to print in textarea or email you can use

```
 <textarea>
    <?php echo $send; ?>
 </textarea>
```

If you want to print as HTML, try

```
<?php echo nl2br($send); ?>
```

Comment: Any reason for downvote, please care to share reason.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to text in a text area you can try this

```
 $send = "Thank you for registering.&#13; For more details contact us";
 <textarea>
 <?php echo $send; ?>
 </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as the below code.

```
$send = "Thank you for registering with Playit. \n If you have any questions please contact ramesh@emagine.lk.";
```